# C# - Referenciar uma variavel de outro método

Tags: c#

Tenho dois métodos e quero ir buscar uma variável de um método para o outro. Trata-se da variável `base64` que está na função `base64Decode`.
O código é o seguinte:

```
 public class WK_UpdateAlvo : CodeActivity
{
    [Input("StringFile")]
    public InArgument<string> StringFile { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext Execontext)
    {
     ITracingService _tracing;
     try
        {
           AllMethods.Base64Decode(base64);
            _tracing.Trace("base64: {0}", base64);
        }
     catch {
            trhow;
           }
          public class AllMethods
          {
            //decode a string 
            public static string Base64Decode(string stringfile)
            {
              var base64 = System.Convert.FromBase64String(stringfile);
              return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64);
            }
          }
    }
 }
```

Obrigada.

Comment: SImples. Não pode fazer isso. Se tiver controlo sobre a classe, tem que meter num campo.

Comment: @Claudia, bom dia. não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, poderia ser mais objetiva? pelo que vi, você tem um método que codifica uma string para base 64, e quer que utilizar essa variável em outro método e isso?

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel sim é isso

Comment: @BrunoCosta pode exemplificar? Obrigada

Comment: Não sei de onde você pegou esse trecho de código, mas não me parece ser algo bom. essa parte de classe dentro de classe não sei onde você quer chegar com isso, você não referencia variável (Interna) de método  o que pode ser feito é o retorno, ou seja você pode chama seu método e espera a variável de retorno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por aquilo que entendi do seu código, o que você pretende é, em uma classe(*WK_UpdateAlvo*) aceder a um método(`Base64Decode()`) de outra classe(*AllMethods*).

O código já está a chamar esse método na linha

```
AllMethods.Base64Decode(base64);
```

dentro do bloco *try/catch*

Mas da forma que está o código ele nem sequer compila.

A declaração da classe *AllMethods* não pode ser feita dentro de um método.
Deverá ser declarada, preferencialmente, em um arquivo separado, ou ao mesmo nível da outra.

Altere o seu código assim:

```
public class WK_UpdateAlvo : CodeActivity
{
    [Input("StringFile")]
    public InArgument<string> StringFile { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext Execontext)
    {
     ITracingService _tracing;
     try
        {
           AllMethods.Base64Decode(base64);
            _tracing.Trace("base64: {0}", base64);
        }
     catch {
            trhow;
           }
    }
 }

public class AllMethods
{
    public static string Base64Decode(string stringfile)
    {
      var base64 = System.Convert.FromBase64String(stringfile);
      return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64);
    }
}
```

<sub>O código apresenta outros "problemas" mas não são relevantes para o caso.</sub>

Comment: Poderia dar um leve exemplo sobre a funcionalidade do `AllMethods`?

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel, isso é apenas uma classe, acho que ele criou com esse nome com intuito de ter todos seu métodos dentro dela.

Comment: Ha perfeito. obrigado.

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel *AllMethods* é uma *helper classe*. Esse tipo de classes tem métodos, normalmente estáticos, que, pela sua natureza, não pertencem a nenhuma classe em particular.

Answer (score 1):

Observe que, ao criar uma classe, podemos definir algumas variáveis de entrada, exemplo:

```
class Cadastro_obsClie
{
    // Neste caso minhas variaveis de entrada são, id_cliente, data, titulo e descricao
    public int cadastro_obs_cliente(int id_cliente, string data, string titulo, string descricao)
    {
        // método qualquer.
    }
}
```

Quando vamos instanciar uma classe, devemos informar quais as variáveis corresponde as minhas variáveis de entrada, exemplo:

```
// Instanciando a classe Cadastro_obsClie
Cadastro_obsClie cad_obsClie = new Cadastro_obsClie();

// Chamamos o metodo cadastro_obs_cliente
// repare que estou passando as variáveis de entrada para o metodo
cad_obsClie.cadastro_obs_cliente(id_cliente, DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), "Cadastro", "Cadastro inicial - Cliente inserido no banco de dados.");
```

Então, ao construir a sua classe, deve parametrizar a variável de entrada, e ao fazer o instanciamento deve informar a variável.

Comment: Ou seja, na minha função tenho que colocar a variável `base64` como parâmetro? Desta forma: 
`public static string Base64Decode(string stringfile, byte[] base64)`
Está correto?

Comment: Não, você tem que colocar esse parametro, na classe que vai instanciar, pelo que entendi, a classe Base64Decode, codifica uma string em base64 e essa string você quer usar em outra classe, então na outra classe você deve parametrizar a string que esta enviando. obs: o metodo Base64Decode esta retornando uma string, por isso deve ser parametrizado como `public void outraclasse(string nomedavariavel)`

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigada.